# Test bodies general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I'm studying section 82 of the Landau & Lifshitz Field Theory vol.2 
In [this page](https://ia701209.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/27/items/TheClassicalTheoryOfFields/LandauLifshitz-TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_jp2.zip&file=LandauLifshitz-TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_jp2/LandauLifshitz-TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_0239.jp2&scale=4&rotate=0)
it's written that the relative position of test bodies can't remain unchanged during time. And ok with this. But then on the footnote they write

> *Strictly speaking, the number of particles should be greater than four. Since we can construct a tetrahedron from any six line segments, we can always, by a suitable definition of the reference system, make a system of four particles from an invariant tetrahedron. A fortiori, we can fix the particles relative to one another in systems of three or two particles.*

What does this mean?

Comment: They are describing how to use the gauge freedom of coordinate choice to fix the relative positions of particles.

Comment: I thought they meant you need to use enough particles to demonstrate how things work in 3+1 dimensions. If you only use two particles, one above the other, you will see how the tidal force pulls them apart as they descend over time. That demonstrates how things work in 1+1 dimensions, but doesn't give the whole picture.

Comment: I don't understand why with 4 or less particles the relative positions doesn't change or how we can create a rigid/invariant tetrahedron.